# Are visitors of my website and php files always in permission-class other?

Tags: file-permissions

I am trying to understand how to setup file permissions on my server. I read the awesome guide https://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver.

**1. visitors of my website**

The guide states

> Anonymous users are the visitors to your website. Although they don't have
>   permissions to access files directly, they can request a web page and
>   the web server acts on their behalf. You can limit the access of
>   anonymous users by being careful about what permissions the web server
>   process has. On many Linux distributions, Apache runs as the www-data
>   user but it can be different. Use ps aux | grep httpd or ps aux | grep
>   apache to see what user Apache is using on your system.

I am using XAMPP on my laptop. If I enter `ps aux | grep httpd` I get

```
adam      6635  0.0  0.0  21292   960 pts/1    S+   15:51   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

So Apache runs as `adam`. Further I have a file called `test2.php` with the following permission:

```
-r-------- 1 adam adam 24 Dez 31 15:20 test2.php
```

So only the owner of the file can read it. But since Apache is the owner, I expected that if I request the file in my browser I should be able to read it.

However, I get the following error

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown
>   on line 0
>
> Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required
>   '/home/adam/www/site/test2.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')
>   in Unknown on line 0

But isn't the above quote suggesting that I should be able to access it because of

> they can request a web page and the web server acts on their behalf.

**2. PHP Files**

Consider a  php file consisting of

```
<?php

 $string = fopen("stuff.txt","r");
```

is the php file able to open `stuff.txt` only iff `stuff.txt` is readable for the permission class `other`? Or would it also be readable if Apache is the owner of the file and has read permission but the permission class `other` has no read permission?

Comment: It all depends on your operating system setup. Some distributions protect home directories so that other users cannot access it. Furthermore, the full path leading to the filename must have `execute` permissions for the web server process.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen so depending on my os it is in generall possible that visitiors can access files through the browser which have no read permissions for the class `other`? I am using XAMPP on my laptop with OS ubuntu 16.04 - where can I find/edit these specific OS settings?

Comment: Note that the line that makes you think Apache runs as user "adam" really just shows that the `grep` process runs as "adam", it doesn't show an Apache process.  This is due to the fact that this grep will always match itself in the process list.

Answer (score 0):

PHP may run in different mode of operation, if PHP compiled as module of Apache(which is a case for XAMPP) then everything what Apache can see will be available for PHP and since PHP is interpreter language, it can run what it can see(in case it contain `<?php ... ?>` regardless of type of file). If you would run PHP as standalone listening service (using php-fpm) then you can separate Apache from PHP. Apache in this case will be just forwarding proxy to PHP. This way you can run Apache and PHP under different user accounts.

Keep in mind that even you install XAMPP under root/administrator it will drop privileged permission after binding listening port to the user account specified in apache's configuration.

To be able to run web server on port 80 (privileged port) Apache need root/administrator permissions to start, but after start it will run as a regular(preferably restricted) user

XAMPP/LAMPP usually isn't in use in production since it has by default very permissive settings and mostly used on development stage.

If you want production security model, then separate all roles of each service and run each service(Apache, PHP, MySQL) under different, restricted(non administrative) account.

A good security model is when everything(all accessible by Apache) exposed to the wild Internet should have read only permissions except those files or directories that really need to be writable, but in such cases you need restrict those resources in Apache, either by disabling access or turning of PHP engine in such directories depending on use case.

Back to your questions:
You wrote that you using XAMPP which means you running it under windows. Make a right click on task bar and run task manager to spot name of apache process and user account it running to figure out what permissions PHP would have.

But I guess you running LAMPP, not XAMPP since your web directory looks like unix based environment "/home/adam/www/site/test2.php". It very different from windows. Depending on OS you use, Apache service could run under different name instead of httpd, it could be an apache2 (on debian), so when you trying to spot running process, use correct name in `grep`. (To simplify your live, install `htop` on unix based system to spot process's activity)

If I'm right that you use LAMPP, check web directory permissions and its sub-directories that are all owned by the same user as apache user running. If you need file base protection of some file(s), take out ownership to a user different from the user assigned for web service.

Comment: XAMPP is also available for Linux.

Comment: Yes, but if you install it on Linux, you would run it as `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`, that's why I referencing to Linux's XAMPP as LAMPP